# Sorting Scripture Verses with SORT Function Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, filter, split

I have a Google sheet for storing cross references and I want to automatically sort those cross references in ascending order based on the New Testament verses.

| NT Book | NT Chapter | NT Verse | OT Parallel Book | OT Chapter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Matthew | 1 | 1:12 | 1 Chronicles | 3 |
| Matthew | 1 | 1:12 | 1 Chronicles | 3 |
| Matthew | 1 | 1:12 | Ezra | 3 |
| Matthew | 1 | 1:2 | 1 Chronicles | 1 |
| Matthew | 1 | 1:3 | 1 Chronicles | 2 |

I'd to be able to sort by the NT Verse column in ascending order. However, due to the Scripture references, you can see that reference 1:12 is smaller than 1:2 when it should be larger.

I also am trying to do this with a =SORT Function on a query:

`=SORT(QUERY({'1 Chronicles'!A:O,Ezra!A:O}, 'select Col4, Col5, Col1, Col2, Col3, where Col4 contains 'Matthew' order by Col3 ASC",0),3,true)`

So in other words, I need to sort by the NT Verse column in ascending order in a way that retains the order of the verse numbers on the right side of the colon.

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this by formatting the column or with the =SORT function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=SORT(A2:E, INDEX(SPLIT(C2:C, ":"),,1), 1, INDEX(SPLIT(C2:C, ":"),,2), 1)
```

[image]

Comment: This definitely works, I just need to figure out the best for implementing my existing formula with what you have here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `SPLIT` function, keeping everything contained in the query. Use `ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(X:X,":"))` as part of the query's first argument (where X is your `NT Verse` column), then add `order by Col6, Col7` to the end of the query's second argument. The `SORT` function is not necessary.

Here's an example, although I could not test it as you have not provided a full sample data set.

```
=QUERY({{'1 Chronicles'!A:E;Ezra!A:E},ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT({'1 Chronicles'!C:C;Ezra!C:C},":"))}, "select Col4, Col5, Col1, Col2, Col3, where Col4 contains 'Matthew' order by Col6, Col7",0)
```

My locale uses semicolons to separate an array by column, whereas it seems yours uses commas. Make sure to adjust appropriately. Also note that I changed the single quote that begins your query's second argument to a double quote, assuming it was a typo.

Comment: This is definitely useful, but I will have to tinker with it more in order to convert my formula into just a pure query. Thanks for your help!